# Angular 4 - Project compiles to watch but will not build

Tags: angular

I am experiencing a strange error when using ng serve and ng build for an Angular 4 project I am working on.

When I use ng build to build and watch the project, it works about half of the time and compiles successfully. However, the next time I try to use ng build I get this error...

```html
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'require'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 54:13 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in D:/xampp/htdocs/d5/src/app/app.module.ts

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\xampp\htdocs\d5\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

If I then make any change to my app.module.ts (Like add a semi colon, or add or delete a blank line, ng serve will then compile successfully. This has been a pain, but I have at least figured out how to get it to work.

I have just tried to do an ng build to start to learn how to deploy an app and I am getting the same error message...

```html
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'require'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 54:13 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in D:/xampp/htdocs/d5/src/app/app.module.ts

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\xampp\htdocs\d5\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

However, making changes to app.module.ts does not allow ng build to successfully build the app.

What is going on here ? What am I missing ?

Comment: You need to export the require fuction

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more specific on where and how to do that ?

Comment: Actually on haven't managed to do it myself, also it might not be prudent since angular is using webpack for dependency managment